# My stylesheet doesn't appear in theme-editor

Tags: theme-customizer

I don't know why this is happening, but my stylesheet doesn't appear in theme editor. 
It's only the archive style.css. The another templates appears normally.
In the header.php, I'm using this code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_uri(); ?>" />
```

But I tried this too:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_uri(); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

And doesn't work.
I found the following code in codex.wordpress and the problem persists.

```
function my_theme_add_editor_styles() {
    add_editor_style( 'custom-editor-style.css' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_theme_add_editor_styles' );
```

I don't know what more I can do.
[image]

```
/******** 
* Theme Name: Theme 2014
* Description: Theme 2014 - My theme 2014. 
* Version: 3
* Author: J
* Author URI: 
* Theme URI: 
* Tags: Black, White, Minimalist
********/
```

Comment: Is the problem is that the editor doesn't load the content of style.css file from your theme? If so, can you post the [header section of the style.css file](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Theme_Stylesheet)?

Comment: Exactly! I will edit my question.

Comment: have you tried without the extra leading * characters per line: http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Theme_Stylesheet ?

Comment: Yes, I have tested, but still not working.

Comment: Never ever add styles and scripts directly to your header. It causes many headaches for child theme authors and just in general when you need to dequeue styles and scripts

Comment: The headers you posted looks fine. I've tested them and works.

Answer (score -2):

try

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_uri(); ?>/path/to/custom-editor-style.css" />
```

Check encoding your stylesheet on server

Comment: Please explain _why_ this answer is helpful.

Comment: I tried, but the problem persists :s